# BeautifulSoup tag replacement

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

On input i have html:

```
<p>word1<br>word2</p>
```

I need that `<br>` tag will replace with `</p><p>` and output will be:

```
<p>word1</p><p>word2</p>
```

I try just replace `<br>` with `<p>` - tag:

```
# PARAGRAPH TAG
for i in soup.findAll({'p' : True}):
    if len(i.text) == 0:
        i.extract()
    # BR IN PARAGRAPHS
    for br in i.findAll({'br' : True}):
        paragraphTag = soup.new_tag("p")
        br.replaceWith(paragraphTag)
```

But in output i have:

```
<p>word1</p><p/>word2
```

I try to replace `<br>` with string `</p><p>` but this variant does not work too, because `<` and `>` replaced on their codes

```
<p>lorem&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;lorem2</p>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "< and > replaced on their codes"? Did you try to do the replacement without BeautifulSoup?

Comment: No i don't try to replace without BeautifulSoup, add code to question (судя по вашему имени, хочется не ломать язык кривым английским, вы сидите на русском so?)

Comment: I mean, did you try just `s = open(html_file).read().replace('<br>', '</p><p>')`? (I don't use the Russian SO, and the language of this SO is English...)

Comment: okay) I don't need replace all '<br>', i need to replace only <br> that are DOM-childs of <p>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't need bs4.

```
html="<p>word1<br>word2</p>"
html='</p><p>'.join(html.split('<br>'))
```